# Matplotlib animation error : Requested MovieWriter (ffmpeg) not available, while ffmpeg is installed

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, ffmpeg

I'm trying to animate colormapping representations of parametric complex fonctions using Python.
I gradually put some things together, and checked that they worked properly. But I can't get the animation to be saved.

I encountered this error :

`Requested MovieWriter (ffmpeg) not available`

However, ffmpeg is indeed installed on my system,
on Windows console `ffmpeg -version` returns all sorts of informations about ffmpeg. Additionnaly, I also installed ffmpeg in Python scripts directory using pip `pip install ffmpeg`, which was successfull. I also set up ffmepg path in my code : `plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = "C:\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"`

I'm runing out of ideas.

Here is my code.
Thank you for reading.

```py
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
pi=math.pi
plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = "C:\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"
fig = plt.figure()

def complex_array_to_rgb(X, theme='dark', rmax=None):
  absmax = rmax or np.abs(X).max()
  Y = np.zeros(X.shape + (3,), dtype='float')
  Y[..., 0] = np.angle(X) / (2 * pi) % 1
  if theme == 'light':
    Y[..., 1] = np.clip(np.abs(X) / absmax, 0, 1)
    Y[..., 2] = 1
  elif theme == 'dark':
    Y[..., 1] = 1
    Y[..., 2] = np.clip(np.abs(X) / absmax, 0, 1)
  Y = matplotlib.colors.hsv_to_rgb(Y)
  return Y

# Set up formatting for the movie files
Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=15, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)

fps = 10
nSeconds = 1
snapshots = [ complex_array_to_rgb(np.array([[3*(x + 1j*y)**(2.9+p/300) + 1/(x + 1j*y)**2 for x in np.arange(-1,1,0.05)] for y in np.arange(-1,1,0.05)])) for p in range( nSeconds * fps ) ]

fig = plt.figure( figsize=(3,3) )

Z2=snapshots[0]
im=plt.imshow(Z2, extent=(-1,1,-1,1))

def animate_func(i):
    if i % fps == 0:
        print( '.')

    im.set_array(snapshots[i])
    return [im]
    
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(
                               fig, 
                               animate_func, 
                               frames = nSeconds * fps,
                               interval = 1000 / fps, # in ms
                               )

anim.save('test_anim.mp4', writer=writer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python uses backward slashes in strings for escape characters, so these are messing with your file path. Try using either

```
plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = "C:/FFmpeg/bin/ffmpeg"
```

or, a bit messier

```
plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = "C:\\FFmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg"
```

If that doesn't work either, you could try using the ffmpeg writer class directly:

```
FFwriter = animation.FFMpegWriter()
```

Answer (score 0):

With Windows10 & JupyterLab

I've done some animations times ago and it worked well... but a few days ago I used the very same notebook/computer and it fails, giving the error

```
RuntimeError: Requested MovieWriter (ffmpeg) not available
```

And surely the FFmpeg was there! After a search, I found out that there is more than one, associated with other software (OBS, Shotcut, etc).

After trying many things, the only thing that worked was to download a build (https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/) and add the address like this in the notebook (including the 'ffmpeg.exe')

```
plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = r'c:\FFMPEG\ffmpeg-2021-10-14-git-c336c7a9d7-full_build\bin\ffmpeg.exe'
```